# read a single line in php

Tags: php, input, readfile

I have a file with 20 lines , with 3 numbers in each line... separated by spaces..
I just need to read 1 line at a time so that i can store those 3 number in an array... and use them in the code...the next time it should read the 2nd line and store in the array..and soon..how should i proceed ..
i have tried fgets

```
 $fh = fopen($argv[1], "r");
    while($i<=20)
    {
    $line = trim($fh);
    $str=explode($line);
    }
```

and this as well...

```
$i=1;
while($i<=20)
{
$lines = file($argv[1], FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES | FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
foreach ($lines as $l){}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

function ReadLineNumber($file, $number)
{
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $i = 0;
    while (fgets($handle) && $i < $number - 1)
        $i++;
    return fgets($handle);
}
?>
```

this example for Read single line from a big text file .try this

Comment: This is quite nice and generic. But for this specific case it would be quite expensive, going over every line all the time to get to the required line. O(n^2) solution.

Answer (score 4):

Use [fgetcsv()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) - don't forget to set the delimiter to space.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fgets like this:

```
$fh = fopen($argv[1], "r");
if ($fh) 
{
    while (($line = fgets($fh)) !== false) 
    {
        // process the line read.
    }
} 
else 
{
    // error
} 

// Close the handle
fclose($fh);
```